# Missing VennDiagram Information?

Tags: statistics, elementary-set-theory

I am currently trying to complete a Venn Diagram for my high School Statistics Class but I feel as if there is some information missing so that I cant find every element of the Venn diagram.

The question is as follows, Given the following information find every element of the Venn diagram, Suppose there is a school with 1500 Students Attending,

- 480 Are taking neither (Math or English),
- 750 students are taking English,
- 105 students are taking Math and Science.
- 180 Students are taking Science And Not Math And Not English. And finally,
- 270 are taking Math and Either English OR science.

Subjects are noncompulsory so students could exist who do not take any of the classes. I just can't find the two shaded areas shown in my picture below, any ideas how i can find the values? Sorry for the super long one, just been stuck on it for hours and I need to hopefully know for tomorrows class.

Thanks for reading and I hope you might be wiser then myself. Here is my attempt to far as well, 3 variables are M E S representing Math English And Science.

[Picture Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AODAD.jpg)

[image]

Thanks if anyone has any ideas cause im really stuck

Comment: I have tried to edit you question so it is easier to read. Also, made your picture visible in the question. Please explain how you found counts for some of the regions of the Venn diagram. // One overall strategy might be to start by making many sketches of with the 3 circles.  Then shade areas for each bullet point in a separate sketch. (Be especially careful with sketches for the the last two bullets.) Finally, try to put counts in each of the eight regions.